# ADB - Can't enable USB Debugging, phone stuck on boot screen

Tags: adb, usb-debugging

My phone stopped working and stays stuck on the boot screen. I've tried wiping both cache partition and data reset, still nothing. So I decided to flash a new ROM, but I can't connect through ADB as my USB debugging is not on. Is there any way for this to work?

I use a Freetel FTE171A.

Answer (score 0):

This phone is an SPD device this means that you don't need fastboot or ADB for flashing. What you need is USB drivers and A flashing program and eventually the flash files (ROM).

Go to this [link](https://naijarom.com/freetel-fte171a-ice3-emea) to download everything you'll need.